# Assigning 2 digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

The variables $a$ and $b$ are randomly assigned a two-digit positive integer value, independently of each other. What is the probability that $ab+a$ is divisible by $3$?

For this problem, I know that if ab and a are both divisible by 3, then it isn’t hard to calculate. The problem is that they don’t have to be divisible by 3, so I don’t know how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of a $2$-digit number to be divisible by $3$ is $p=1/3$

$a(b+1)$ must be divisible by 3

Either $a$ is divisible by $3$ or $b+1$ is divisble by $3$

$$P=1/3+1/3-(1/3)^2=5/9$$

Answer (score 0):

$a$ and $b$ are two-digit positive integers, meaning that they have an equal probability of being $0, 1, 2$ mod $3$. (We can verify this by considering that there are $90$ two-digit numbers, and these can be partitioned into sets $\{10, 13, \dots 97\}, \{11, 14, \dots, 98\}, \{12, 15, \dots, 99\}$, each of which has $30$ elements.)

Now from this point, we can just consider each of the $9$ possibilities for $a$ and $b$ mod $3$. There are $5$ cases where $ab+a$ is divisible by 3, namely $(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,2)$. Each of the $9$ possibilities is equally likely to happen, so our probability is $\frac{5}{9}$.

Answer (score 0):

$a$ and $b$ are $2$-digit positive integers, so $\, a,b \in \{1,2,3,...,99\}$.

There are exactly $33$ numbers in $\{1,2,3,...,99\}$ that are divisible by $3$, namely

$$\{3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99\}$$

The same statement is true for $\; b+1\in\{2,3,4,...,100\}$. $$$$

\begin{align} P\left(3 \;\text{divides} \; ab+a \right)&= P\left(3 \;\text{divides} \; a(b+1)\right) \\ &= P\left(3 \;\text{divides} \; a\;\text{OR}\; 3 \;\text{divides} \; b+1\right) \\ 
&=P\left(3 \;\text{divides} \; a\right)+P\left(3 \;\text{divides} \; b+1\right)-P\left(3 \;\text{divides} \; a\;\text{AND}\; 3 \;\text{divides} \; b+1\right) \\
&=\frac{33}{99}+\frac{33}{99}-\frac{33}{99}\cdot\frac{33}{99} \\ 
&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3} \\
&=\frac{5}{9}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b$ are two digit intergers, $\mathrm{Prob}\{a \bmod 3 = i\}=\mathrm{Prob}\{b \bmod 3 = i\}=\frac13$, for all $i\in\{0,1,2\}$.
\begin{align} \mathrm{Prob}\{ab+a \bmod 3 =0\}&= \mathrm{Prob}\{a \bmod 3 = 0 \text{ or } b +1 \bmod 3 = 0\}\\
&= \mathrm{Prob}\{a \bmod 3 = 0 \} + \mathrm{Prob}\{ b +1 \bmod 3 = 0\}\\
&\hspace{3cm}-\mathrm{Prob}\{a \bmod 3 = 0 \text{ and }b +1 \bmod 3 = 0\}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{9}.
\end{align}